# How to make php return cyrillic words as a result of search engine

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need my php search engine to return cyrillic words if there is a matches in SQL and return them as a result.My ajax is working fine and POSTing cyrillic characters [image: example]

But i guess the problem comes from php when it receive the character it is probably encoding it and character from асд will become something like 0%D0%BD%D0%B8 So there is my code:

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<div id="food_search_result">
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              PHP 
----------------------------------------------------------------->
  if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];

$req = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE ?");
$value = '%'.$fsearch.'%';
$req->bind_param('s', $value);
$req->execute();
$req->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $req->num_rows;
$req->bind_result($title);
if ($req->num_rows == 0){

echo 'Няма резултати';
}
else{
while($data=$req->fetch()){
   ?>
       <div class="search-result">
           <span class="result-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
       </div>
       <?php
       }
$req->free_result();
    }
}
?>
```

So just to clarify to be easier for you guys to help me.1.Information is sended from HTML input field to AJAX 2.Ajax posting that information in php form.3.Php get that information and check if there is match in SQL database.4.Php return result if there is any,if there is not result it returns a echo 'Няма намерени резултати' Which means no results has been found in Bulgarian.

The things which i have tried already are:

1.Edit Encrypt type in my html form.

2.Tried to add function like [This](http://bitprison.net/php_mail_utf-8_subject_and_message) One.

3.Add a meta tag for UTF-8 Characters.
Nothing worked.

Comment: Don't understand your problem... PHP doesn't search in DB or it does but returns decoded search result?

Comment: Well i am not sure either... Guess when cyrillic characters are passed from ajax to php,PHP is decrypting them like   0%D0% And it does't find any matches and returns "Няма намерени резултати"(no results has been found)...So i need a way to make PHP read and transfer Cyrillic characters without making them like  0%D0%

Comment: Have you *confirmed* how exactly PHP is receiving the data…? `var_dump($_POST)`…

Comment: First sorry for my slow response.And second it is pasting the RIGHT data but when its not cyrillic there is a picture of string result too http://prntscr.com/e958qi  As you can see it is returning string (3) "kur" But when i write something cyrillic http://prntscr.com/e959jq The both words exist in database but it won't return the cyrillic one ;/

Comment: What is encoding of your front page with form? Is it UTF-8? And what is collation of you 'title' field in DB?

Comment: My Collation is utf8_general_ci.On my page with script there is no encoding set,it is set only in my header as meta tag charset=UTF8.There is a picture of my page http://prntscr.com/e9jiri

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$value = '%'.urldecode($fsearch).'%';
```

and the second variant - try that query right after you make DB connection:

```
$connect->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Don't try both.

Comment: Doesn't work mate and thanks for response and sorry for my slow response i was at university